# "Кого" вместо "Которого" и "коего"

Tags: общие-вопросы

Возможно ли заменять "которого" на "кого"? Например: "это случилось с восхождением на престол Петра, кого мало интересовало..."
Моё мнение — возможно. Однако не случалось встречать такой оборот в устрой речи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На мой взгляд, взаимозаменяемости здесь нет: для употребления "кого" требуется как минимум изменение порядка слов. Вот варианты, которые представляются мне допустимыми и естественными (не просторечными):

> это случилось с восхождением на престол Петра, которого мало
>   интересовало...
>
> это случилось с восхождением на престол того, кого мало
>   интересовало...
>
> кого данное событие мало интересовало, так это Петра

Локальная закономерность здесь такая: "который (-ого)" употребляется *после* явно названной сущности (здесь имя), "кто (кого)" - в менее определённых случаях (*до того*, как сущность названа). При этом (в первых двух примерах) "который" сочетается с именем, а "кто" - с местоимением. Вероятно, нарушение таких сочетаний и создаёт диссонанс при замене "которого" на "кого".